# why I received no output in the following code?

Tags: ruby, erb

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= @weekday %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

The result is Today is . which is not expected. How to fix?

Comment: Did you mean to put a @ in front of weekday?  The example here http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/ does not do that.  Touche someone else made it an answer.

Comment: the example does not work as well, I received an error "undefined local variable or method 'weekday"

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't define `@weekday`. You use instance variable in template, so you need to define it:

```
require 'erb'

@weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= @weekday %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

OR

You can use defined local variable in template:

```
require 'erb'

weekday = Time.now.strftime('%A')
simple_template = "Today is <%= weekday %>."

renderer = ERB.new(simple_template)
puts output = renderer.result()
```

Comment: it does not work if I simply change from weekday to @weekday.

Comment: it  is OK when I run with 2.0.0p481, but failed in another machine. I am still confused, why I can use @weekday, is it an instance variable? if I just use  weekday, I will receive error.

Comment: @AdamLee no matter which type of variable you use, but keep in mind that `weekday` and `@weekday` are 2 completely different variables. See updated answer.

Comment: @ Rustam A. Gasanov, the second one does not work for sure.  received an error "undefined local variable or method 'weekday"

Comment: @AdamLee it works for sure. You can easily check it in console or here http://ideone.com/Ik0FDs No one will be able to answer you, unless you tell more about that mysterious  "other machine"

Comment: Thanks , I am now totally believe. Actually I just checked, running from console has no problem. My Ruby editor use ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) whihc cause the problem, do you have any idea about this?